# Como Insertar Múltiples registros

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$id=$_POST['id'];

    for($i=0;$i<=count($id);$i++){

    $q="INSERT INTO calificaciones (id, nombre, asig, sig, grupo) VALUES ('".$_POST['id_foto'][$i]."','".$_POST['nombre'][$i]."','".$_POST['asig'][$i]."','".$_POST['sig'][$i]."','".$_POST['grupo'][$i]."') "; 
        $result = $conexion->query($q) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $q - Error: ".mysqli_error(), E_USER_ERROR);

      }
```

Realice var_dump($id);

```
array(33) { [0]=> string(9) "id" [1]=> string(9) "id" [2]=> string(9) "id" [3]=> string(9) "id" [4]=> string(9) "id" [5]=> string(9) "id" [6]=> string(9) "id" [7]=> string(9) "id" [8]=> string(9) "id" [9]=> string(9) "id" [10]=> string(9) "id" [11]=> string(9) "id" [12]=> string(9) "id" [13]=> string(9) "id" [14]=> string(9) "id" [15]=> string(9) "id" [16]=> string(9) "id" [17]=> string(9) "id" [18]=> string(9) "id" [19]=> string(9) "id" [20]=> string(9) "id" [21]=> string(9) "id" [22]=> string(9) "id" [23]=> string(9) "id" [24]=> string(9) "id" [25]=> string(9) "id" [26]=> string(9) "id" [27]=> string(9) "id" [28]=> string(9) "id" [29]=> string(9) "id" [30]=> string(9) "id" [31]=> string(9) "id" [32]=> string(9) "id" }
```

y en mi consulta me genera un total de 42 Registros

Solo me esta insertando 33 Registros que puede estar fallando, alguna sugerencia.
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Estas seguro de que en `$_POST['id']` esta el total de registros que envias?

Comment: el único error que podría haber es que $_POST['id']  no sea igual a 40, que sea 34, ya que el código de para insertar y ejecutar están bien realizados

Comment: Hola gracias , si estoy seguro de que le envio un total de 40, ya que antes hago una consulta que es la que me genera ese total de registros y me los genera perfectamente, pero al insertarlos solo me genera unos 34 y no se por que, honestamente

Comment: Suponiendo que el codigo este bien, se me ocurre que puedas teniendo algun limite de consultas a la base de datos por tu hosting, que estes haciendo demasiadas consultas y satures el hosting y/o el motor de base de datos, pero si sabes que tu hosting dentro de todo es de calidad dudo que sea este el problema.

Comment: Hola gracias por la informacion Santiago D'Antuoni tengo un hosting local desde alli pruebo la consulta

Comment: ¿Podrías [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/43628/edit) tu pregunta y agregar el resultado de hacer `var_dump($id)`? Porque si `$id` es igual a `40`, entonces `count($id)` es igual a `1`, por lo que ni siquiera tiene sentido que inserte 34 registros.